# Extrair data de uma String C#

Tags: c#, string, data

Preciso extrair duas datas de uma string quem vem no seguinte formato:

```
string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> 02/03/2018 à > 02/03/2019";
```

Sendo data início e data fim. De forma fixa consigo fazer isso, no entanto essa string pode vir com as datas em branco, ou com apenas a data de início ou apenas a data de fim, dessa forma:

```
string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> à > ";
string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> à > 02/03/2019";
string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> 02/03/2018 à > ";
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para pegar essas datas de forma dinâmica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o código abaixo:

```
string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> 02/03/2018 à > 02/03/2019";
string[] testeSplit = teste.Split('>');

string dataIni, dataFim;

dataIni = testeSplit[1].Replace('à', ' ').Trim();
dataFim = testeSplit[2].Trim();
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar uma descrição da solução?

Comment: Eu adicionar? O que seria?? Você? Sem problemas :P

Comment: A solução é pratica, mas se o script estiver salvo como ASCII e o valor de entrada em `string teste` for Unicode, o `.Replace('à', ' ')` talvez venha a falhar, já que `á` em latin1 é diferente de `à` em utf8, por exemplo.

Comment: Corrigindo minha ultima frase: *... talvez venha a falhar, já que `à` em latin1 é diferente de `à` em utf8.*

Answer (score 5):

Você deve analisar as datas dentro dessa string para garantir que elas sejam datas válidas, assim evita problemas futuros.

Com uma expressão regular e usando o método [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) é possível extrair a data com mais segurança, porém, não executei todos os testes então sugiro que você teste a função abaixo com diversas entradas para verificar se há resultados indesejados.

Imagem de ilustração da regex:

[image: ilustração da regex]

Código da função:

```
List<string> ExtrairDatas(string str)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578])|(1[02]))/31/(19|20)?\d\d)|(?:(?:(?:0?[13-9])|(?:1[0-2]))/(?:29|30)/(?:19|20)?\d\d)|(?:0?2/29/(?:19|20)(?:(?:[02468][048])|(?:[13579][26])))|(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))/(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1\d)|(?:2[0-8]))/(?:19|20)?\d\d))"); 

    var datas = new List<string>();

    foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(str))
    {                   
        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) datas.Add(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }

    return datas;
}
```

Código completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string teste = "Aprovados por autorizantes da aplicação -> 02/03/2018";     

        ExtrairDatas(teste).ForEach(d => WriteLine(d));
    }

    static List<string> ExtrairDatas(string str)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578])|(1[02]))/31/(19|20)?\d\d)|(?:(?:(?:0?[13-9])|(?:1[0-2]))/(?:29|30)/(?:19|20)?\d\d)|(?:0?2/29/(?:19|20)(?:(?:[02468][048])|(?:[13579][26])))|(?:(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))/(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1\d)|(?:2[0-8]))/(?:19|20)?\d\d))"); 

        var datas = new List<string>();

        foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(str))
        {                   
            DateTime dt;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) datas.Add(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }

        return datas;
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8UeZKr).

Fontes:
[Regex to match Date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978549/5429980)
[Get Date from String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222820/5429980)

Comment: Muito bom, mas a aplicação já faz essa validação, mesmo assim muito obrigado !!!